# Android ExceptionInitializerError

Tags: android

I'm getting an "ExceptionInitializerError" on the following line of code:

(Activity 1)

```
Activity2.selection = AudioColumns.ARTIST + "=?";
```

(Activity 2)

```
static String selection;
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

For complete code, see below.

(Activity 1)

```
package awesome.music.player;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.ArtistColumns;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class ArtistsActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    private Cursor artistCursor;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.artistsview);

        String[] artistColumns = { BaseColumns._ID, ArtistColumns.ARTIST };
        // The columns to return for each row.

        artistCursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Audio.Artists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, artistColumns,
                null, null, null);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewArtists);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        // set an on item click listener to the first list view in this activity

        String[] displayFields = new String[] { ArtistColumns.ARTIST };
        // set all the artist names to the array "displayfields"
        int[] displayViews = new int[] { R.id.artistTitle };
        // number of rows to display and where to bind them

        SimpleCursorAdapter artistAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.artistitem, artistCursor, displayFields, displayViews);
        listView.setAdapter(artistAdapter);
    }

    // Take the display fields array, and bind to the matching display row

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
        if (artistCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {

            Playlist.selection = AudioColumns.ARTIST + "=?";

            Playlist.selectionArgs = new String[] { artistCursor
                    .getString(artistCursor.getColumnIndex(AlbumColumns.ARTIST)) };

            Playlist.artist = artistCursor.getString(artistCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(ArtistColumns.ARTIST));

            Intent intent = new Intent(ArtistsActivity.this,
                    ArtistAlbumsActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }

}
```

(Activity 2)

```
package awesome.music.player;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.net.Uri;

public class Playlist {

    static ArrayList<String> pathList = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> artistList = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> albumList = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> durationList = new ArrayList<String>();

    static int currentSongIndex;
    static String currentSongPath;
    static String artist;
    static String album;
    static String albumId;
    static String numSongs;
    static String selection;
    static String[] selectionArgs;
    static String totalSongduration; // Set

    static String songDuration = durationList.get(currentSongIndex);

    static String currentAlbumId = Playlist.idList
            .get(Playlist.currentSongIndex);

    static Integer currentAlbumIdLong = Integer.parseInt(currentAlbumId);

    static Uri artworkUri = Uri
            .parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");

    static Uri currentSongUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(artworkUri,
            currentAlbumIdLong);;

    static int totalSongDuration = Integer.parseInt(songDuration);

}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use `Static` its a bad habit, Instead using "static" make an Object the class and use it.

```
public class Playlist {

    ArrayList<String> pathList = new ArrayList<String>();
....
...
}
```

Implementing.

```
public class ArtistsActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    private Playlist mPlaylist;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.artistsview);
        mPlaylist= new Playlist();
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks hotveryspcy. My worry is that this seems to over complicate my code, I feel like I'm already nearly there..

Comment: hotveryspicy, could you show me how I would use for passing some of the other variables from Activity 1 to Activity 2?

Comment: you can use intent http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html and intent.putExra() and intent.getExtras() will help you to pass the value between activities.

Answer (score 1):

An ExceptionInInitializerError is thrown to indicate that an exception occurred during evaluation of a static initializer or the initializer for a static variable. Check your code has any static initialization logic.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would appreciate it if you would elaborate, as I found the same thing when I typed ExceptionInInitializerError, but it didn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the statics initializations at `Playlist`, like `Integer.parseInt(currentAlbumId);` at the initializatión `currentAlbumId` has `null` value.